# How to access local variable of function from others in Python 3?

Tags: python, function, python-3.5

```
def add():   
    x = input ("Please Enter Your Name: ")
    y = input ("Are you Male or Female (M/F): ")

def newname():
    add()
newname()
```

I want to have access on access on both variables i.e. `"x"` and `"y"` of `add()` fucntion on `newname()` function.
How Can I do it, I am unable to do it with `"global"` as well?

Comment: Why don't you use return x,y in add ?

Comment: Just *return* them from the function, and assign the result to new variables in `newname()`.

Comment: You may want to read a good tutorial on how functions work. I can recommend Think Python (chapters [3](http://greenteapress.com/thinkpython2/html/thinkpython2004.html) and [6](http://greenteapress.com/thinkpython2/html/thinkpython2007.html))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply use `return` :

```
def add():   
    x = input ("Please Enter Your Name: ")
    y = input ("Are you Male or Female (M/F): ")
    return x,y 

def newname():
    x, y = add()

newname()
```

Comment: What will be the case if i am passing parameters in function i.e. add(x,y)?

Comment: If you keep the rest of the code as it is, the values in the parameters won't change.

Comment: @TaimoorPasha have a look at the links GhostlyMartijn provided as a comment to your question.